# How to display the dialog before leaving the page with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make my app display the dialog always before leaving the page. I'm trying to use event beforeunload but it display the dialog only if i do some changes on the webpage. If i just open the page and then leave it dialog is not displayed...

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The document is well explained, so I link it.

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event